# Are there two mutually incompatible consistent sentences in the language of PA, neither of which is true in the standard model?

Tags: lo.logic

Are there sentences $\phi$ and $\psi$ in the language of PA and models $\mathcal{M}_\phi$ and $\mathcal{M}_\psi$ of PA such that $\mathcal{M}_\phi\models\phi$ and $\mathcal{M}_\psi\models\psi$, but $\text{PA}\vdash\neg(\phi\wedge\psi)$ and $\mathbb{N}\models(\neg\phi)\wedge(\neg\psi)$ (where $\mathbb{N}$ is the standard model of PA)?

I assume that the answer is yes, but I do not know how to construct them or even show non-constructively that they exist. [This answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/92099/how-many-models-of-peano-arithmetic-are-isomorphic-to-the-standard-model-and-how#answer-92106) seems to suggest that $\phi :\leftrightarrow \neg\text{Con}(\text{PA})\wedge\text{Con}(\text{PA}+\neg\text{Con}(\text{PA}))$ and $\psi :\leftrightarrow \neg\text{Con}(\text{PA})\wedge\neg\text{Con}(\text{PA}+\neg\text{Con}(\text{PA}))$ should work, but it's not obvious to me from the form of the second incompleteness theorem that I'm familiar with that $\phi$ is consistent: $\text{PA}+\neg\text{Con}(\text{PA})$ cannot prove its own consistency, but is it clear that it can't prove its own *inconsistency* either?

Comment: How about $\phi=\neg Con(PA)$ and $\psi=Con(PA) \wedge \neg Con(PA+Con(PA))$?

Comment: D'oh, why didn't I think of that? Thanks, Eric!

Comment: @Benja It seems to me that $\mathtt{PA}+\lnot\mathtt{Con}(\mathtt{PA})$ not only can, but in fact *does* prove its own inconsistency.

Comment: From $PA\vdash Con(PA+\lnot Con(PA))\to Con(PA)$ you obtain $PA\vdash\lnot Con(PA)\to\lnot Con(PA+\lnot Con(PA))$ and thus $PA+\lnot Con(PA)\vdash\lnot Con(PA+\lnot Con(PA))$

Comment: @Benja, if I am honest, I am not sure my premise is true in the above argument. Going back to my notes....

Comment: @NoelVaillant Ah, I see -- the comment I linked to uses [the Rosser sentence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rosser%27s_trick#The_Rosser_sentence), not Con(T). By [Rosser's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rosser%27s_trick#Rosser.27s_theorem), both the Rosser sentence for T and its negation is consistent with T, resolving my confusion. Thanks!

Comment: Benja, you linked to my answer in your question, but the tree there was built using the Rosser sentence to branch at each node, rather than the consistency sentences. This allows one to surmount the problem you are facing with the fact that the inconsistency of PA implies the inconsistency of any extension of PA. (And that is easy to prove, since any proof from PA is also a proof from any stronger theory.)

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins Right, missed that initially, thanks!

Comment: @NoelVaillant As Joel points out, if $\neg\text{Con(PA)}$, then there is a proof of a contradiction from the axioms of $\text{PA}$, which is also a proof of a contradiction from the axioms of $\text{PA} + \neg\text{Con(PA)}$, so I think your reasoning is just fine.

Comment: @Benja Let $T=PA$, $\phi=\lnot Con(PA)$ and $T'=T+\phi$. Yes, the inconsistency of $T$ implies that of $T'$, and it does so provably, i.e. $T\vdash Con(T')\to Con(T)$ (as I claimed earlier). If this is not clear to you (it wasn't to me), with obvious notation $Axiom_{T'}(n)=Axiom_{T}(n)\lor(n=\ulcorner\phi\urcorner)$. This will mess up the Godel numbering of proofs so we can't argue that $T\vdash Prf_{T}[n,m]\to Prf_{T'}[n,m]$, but we shall have  $T\vdash \exists n Prf_{T}[n,m]\to \exists n Prf_{T'}[n,m]$.

Comment: @Benja sorry I missed your comment, thank you !

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it appears to have been answered very easily in the comments.